# URLRewrite IIS 7 Help Needed

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

Here is my settings for IIS 7 URL Rewrite:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
          <match url="^Articles/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="articledetails.aspx?articleid={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Unfortunately, my page at the following url is not displayed at all:

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/723_Introduction_to_IPhone_Development.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are giving in the wrong URL.

```
<match url="^Articles/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
```

The above rule will match `/Articles/723/Introduction_to_Iphone_Development`. You are giving it `/Articles/723_Introduction_to_Iphone_Development` (underscore instead of slash). Seems that you fixed it as I am typing this though :)